# kinect /scan data format

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, scan, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just a quick question, does the scan (http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) topic's ranges array hold 360 values each representing a degree in a circle for the microsoft kinect?

For example, I've realized that index 180 (or 179?) is directly in front of the camera, does that make the next index 1 degree to the left/right?

One more explanation for clarity, sorry i'm having trouble explaining this in a manner i feel is clear, the kinect is vertex A, do depth scan ranges[180] and ranges[181] make a 1 degree angle at vertex A?

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39192/kinect-/scan-data-format/) by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 600 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on 2012-07-18**:
also is there a simple way to overlap the /scan data array onto the rgb data array? I guess I would just need to know what row the /scan topic is using but i'm not sure where to find that.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-07-19**:
Are you talking about the depth image, a laser scanner or the kinect-transformed-to-laserscan?

**Comment by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on 2012-07-22**:
sorry, im talking about the kinect-to-laserscan, a topic called /scan, the one the navigation stack uses to build 2-d maps on the turtlebot; http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The values you are looking for are:

```
float32 angle_min        # start angle of the scan [rad]
float32 angle_max        # end angle of the scan [rad]
float32 angle_increment  # angular distance between measurements [rad]
```

The i-th range corresponds to angle: angle_min + i * angle_increment. Two consecutive ranges are always angle_increment apart. You should read those out for the kinect specifics, but I doubt that they are full 360 deg as that wouldn't make sense.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on 2012-07-23**:
thanks for the info!